# How to calculate time weighted average using Python?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, data-manipulation, weighted-average

So i have data with irregular intervals in a day.

| Event Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 17-5-2021 03:00 | 84.9 |
| 17-5-2021 11:00 | 84.9 |
| 17-5-2021 15:00 | 84.7 |
| 17-5-2021 23:00 | 84.7 |
| 18-5-2021 03:00 | 84.5 |
| 18-5-2021 11:00 | 84.5 |
| 18-5-2021 15:00 | 84.9 |
| 18-5-2021 23:00 | 84.9 |

I want to calculate time weighted average using python on the above data as value was only 83.7 for 37.5% (9 hours out of 24) where as if calculate normal average it will be accounted for 50% for 17-5-2021.

Assumption: If we don't have value for particular interval then last available value is taken eg: value at 17-5-2021 04:00 is 84.9 as that was the last available value.
Any input would be helpful as I am not able to figure a right way to approach this.
Expected output:

[Please see the image for Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TArPn.png)

Final result

| Event Time | Weighted Average |
| --- | --- |
| 17-5-2021 | 84.79166 |
| 18-5-2021 | 84.71666 |

Comment: Is the data formatted as you've shown (on a single line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use pandas **diff**, **groupby** and **rolling** function to achieve this. You can use the following steps to achieve this:

1. Convert Event Time into datetime
2. Calculate the time difference between consecutive times using diff function and get the difference as seconds using total_seconds and divide it by 3600 to convert in hours.
3. Compute the weighted values by taking product of Value and time difference
4. Compute the weighted average using rolling function. Keep the window length as 2. Divide this by sum of hours in the period. Here it is 12 hrs
5. Compute the daily average of weighted values using groupby and transform. Time start is 12AM
6. Compute Rolling daily average by setting datetimeindex and passing window as 1D.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['Event Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'])
df['Time Diff'] = df['Event Time'].diff(periods=1).dt.total_seconds()/3600
df['Time Diff'] = df['Time Diff'].fillna(4) 
# You dont need to do the above step in large data. Dropping would be better for large data
df['Weighted Value'] = df['Value']*df['Time Diff']
# calculate the weighted average based on number of periods
df['Weighted Average'] = df['Weighted Value'].rolling(2).sum()/12
# calculate average for each day.day starts at 12AM
df['Daily Weighted Fixed Window'] = df.groupby(df['Event Time'].dt.date)['Weighted Value'].transform('sum')/24
# calculate the weighted average for last one day (stats from current time minus 24 hours)
df.set_index('Event Time', inplace=True)
df['Daily Weighted Rolling'] = df['Weighted Value'].rolling('1D').sum()/24
```

| Event Time | Value | Time Diff | Weighted Value | Weighted Average | Daily Weighted Fixed Window | Daily Weighted Rolling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-17 03:00:00 | 84.9 | 4 | 339.6 | nan | 84.8 | 14.15 |
| 2021-05-17 11:00:00 | 84.9 | 8 | 679.2 | 84.9 | 84.8 | 42.45 |
| 2021-05-17 15:00:00 | 84.7 | 4 | 338.8 | 84.8333 | 84.8 | 56.5667 |
| 2021-05-17 23:00:00 | 84.7 | 8 | 677.6 | 84.7 | 84.8 | 84.8 |
| 2021-05-18 03:00:00 | 84.5 | 4 | 338 | 84.6333 | 84.7 | 84.7333 |
| 2021-05-18 11:00:00 | 84.5 | 8 | 676 | 84.5 | 84.7 | 84.6 |
| 2021-05-18 15:00:00 | 84.9 | 4 | 339.6 | 84.6333 | 84.7 | 84.6333 |
| 2021-05-18 23:00:00 | 84.9 | 8 | 679.2 | 84.9 | 84.7 | 84.7 |

I have update the answer. If you need anything more let me know.

Comment: Thanks,but how do i then group based on dates this to get weighted average for each day ?For eg: as per the data in above table there will be 2 values as output one average for 17th May and other for 18th May. Weighted average for 17th would be based on 4 values from 17th and similarly for 18th would be based on 4 values from 18th.

Comment: I have updated my answer to support you @goel89

Comment: Thanks, but what i need is slightly different. I do not need the rolling average,instead i need average for a day. I have added the calculation part in the post along with the final expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've parsed the data appropriately, you can use `datetime` to translate the dates/times as, for example,

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('17-5-2021 03:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

This will create a `datetime` object `datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 17, 3, 0)`.

The `timedelta` object can then be computed between two subsequent (valid) values, just by subtracting the two `datetime` objects. To get a weight for the value, you could use the `.total_seconds()` method of the resulting `timedelta` object.

For example, these two entries `17-5-2021 11:00 84.9 17-5-2021 15:00 84.7` may be used to compute the weight for the 2nd as

```
w=(datetime.strptime(t2,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')-datetime.strptime(t1,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')).total_seconds()
```

where, of course,

```
t1='17-5-2021 11:00'
t2='17-5-2021 15:00'
```

and the result is w=14400.

Assuming you have your data in a list of tuples, as

```
b="""17-5-2021 03:00        84.9
17-5-2021 11:00     84.9
17-5-2021 15:00     84.7
17-5-2021 23:00     84.7
18-5-2021 03:00     84.5
18-5-2021 11:00     84.5
18-5-2021 15:00     84.9
18-5-2021 23:00     84.9""".split()
items=[(' '.join(b[i:i+2]),float(b[i+2])) for i in range(0,len(b),3)]
```

which yield for `items`

```
[('17-5-2021 03:00', 84.9), ('17-5-2021 11:00', 84.9), ('17-5-2021 15:00', 84.7), ('17-5-2021 23:00', 84.7), ('18-5-2021 03:00', 84.5), ('18-5-2021 11:00', 84.5), ('18-5-2021 15:00', 84.9), ('18-5-2021 23:00', 84.9)]
```

then you can sum up each individual (w * val) and divide by the total duration in the end, as

```
t1,val1=items[0]
dt1=datetime.strptime(t1,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
dt0=dt1
result=0.
for item in items[1:]:
  t2,val2=item
  if val2==None: val2=val1 # if value doesn't exist, use previous
  dt2=datetime.strptime(t2,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
  result+=val2*(dt2-dt1).total_seconds()
  dt1=dt2
  val1=val2

result/=(dt1-dt0).total_seconds()
```

If the value is not available, I've assumed `None`. This won't work if the first value doesn't exist, of course.

I'll just mention, for the table you've provided, the result is `84.73636363636363`.

Comment: Thanks i get this part. But how do i apply this to my full dataset where by I calculate the weighted average for each day?   I have modified my data so that it is easier to understand

Comment: Please see my edit, which treats the entire dataset. I had to make assumptions about the format of the input data. But the format used can be gotten by copy/paste of what's in your table.

Comment: Thanks,but how do i now group this based on dates to get weighted average for each day ?For eg: as per the data in above table there will be 2 values as output one average for 17th May and other for 18th May. Weighted average for 17th would be based on 4 values from 17th and similarly for 18th would be based on 4 values from 18th.

Comment: So you'd want to insert a midnight for each day, to start and stop. An additional item you'd need to specify is, which value to use up until midnight for day N-1, and which value to use from midnight to the first time specified for day N. (and, is there potential for skipping days)

Comment: I do not want to modify my actual dataset.So is there a way of achieving this without inserting record.I have updated the post to give an idea on exact calculations and final output